# how do i create a (temporary?) stored procedure to assist making a summary view?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, view, pivot-table

I have view table that looks like this:

[image]

And I started to create a view to summarize by status for each currency:

```
WITH C AS (SELECT * FROM CampaignsPublisherReportSummary)
SELECT
    'Total' T,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PayCurrency='USD' THEN Total END) USD,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PayCurrency='EUR' THEN Total END) EUR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PayCurrency='GBP' THEN Total END) GBP,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PayCurrency='AUD' THEN Total END) AUD
FROM C
UNION
SELECT
    'ToBePaid' T,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PayCurrency='USD' THEN ToBePaid END) USD,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PayCurrency='EUR' THEN ToBePaid END) EUR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PayCurrency='GBP' THEN ToBePaid END) GBP,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PayCurrency='AUD' THEN ToBePaid END) AUD
FROM C
GO
```

[image]

I could finish and get what I want by copy/pasting again for each of the other status (Unverified, Verified, ...etc) but the programmer in me wants to have some kind of function that takes the the status name and runs a templatized version of the query...

QUESTION: Can I do this?  Or is there another better way to break the information down that I'm missing?

UPDATE: My goal is to have something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM #mytempfunc('Total')
UNION SELECT * FROM #mytempfunc('ToBePaid')
UNION ...
```

Comment: I'm not quite certain on what your trying to do. Are you trying to dynamically generate the currency columns? If so, you could do a 'select distinct paycurrency from [current_table]', do a cursor/loop and dynamically build up the query that sums up the total/tobepaid amounts.

Comment: thanks for the feedback - maybe i'm trying to make it complicated when its not. anyway, i did update the question and put when i'm "envisioning" as the goal here...

Comment: If the result of this query is to create a report, in SSRS or similar, let the reporting tool handle the grouping and totals.

Comment: @Tony, thanks for the tip - would you say simple reports are easy to get to in terms of learning curve for SSRS?  Do you know a good starting point for the basics?  I have it installed, i've just never fired it up - my initial dealings with SSIS make me leary, i.e. as a C# programmer trying to accept some DBA responsibilities due to lack of staffing, I feel like a fish outta water sometimes.

Comment: SSRS is not too hard to learn, pick up a copy of "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Step by Step" or "Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services" and you'll be up and running in no time. Since you have paid for the tool already you may as well use it. However, be aware that SSRS reports are not designed to be displayed directly on a web site without some security issues. Hopefully future versions will address this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking; you'd need dynamic SQL to select a field by string value.  However, if your list of metrics is static (and it should be, coming from a view), you may get what you need, or at least a little closer, with `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT PayCurrency, Metric, Amount
FROM CampaignsPublisherReportSummary
UNPIVOT (Amount FOR Metric IN (Paid, ToBePaid, Total)) AS X
```

Comment: Glad to help!  Note that @Tony above is probably right that you should leave the pivoting and formatting to your reporting layer, if possible.  Still, it's good to know how to handle it on the database side too.